# Output records the user doesn't have

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables.

1. `subscription_plans`
2. `subscription_items`

The `subscription_plans` is static and is used to populate the users `subscription_items`. There is a relationship column called `stripe_plan` in both tables.

> What I would like to do is return the `subscription_plans` that the
> current user does not have.

Here are the tables:

**subscription_plans:**

```
+----+--------------------------------+
| id | stripe_plan                    |
+----+--------------------------------+
|  1 | price_1II6H9J763miMe0kHN1FgjuZ |
|  2 | price_1II6H9J763miMe0kSR2icQYx | match 1
|  3 | price_1II6aSJ763miMe0kE7SFp3NN | match 2
|  4 | price_1II6ayJ763miMe0k7Hx1VLlo |
|  5 | price_1II6dGJ763miMe0ke2NfEasu |
|  6 | price_1II6e6J763miMe0kRv6D6cZZ |
|  7 | price_1II6eRJ763miMe0kfNeUZMZw |
|  8 | price_1II6eiJ763miMe0kYelcpWoA |
|  9 | price_1II6fmJ763miMe0kzGRKk1je | match 3
| 10 | price_1II6gBJ763miMe0k0YRSAZMB |
+----+--------------------------------+
```

**subscription_items:**

```
+----+--------------------------------+
| id | stripe_plan                    |
+----+--------------------------------+
|  1 | price_1II6H9J763miMe0kSR2icQYx | match 1
|  2 | price_1II6aSJ763miMe0kE7SFp3NN | match 2
|  3 | price_1II6fmJ763miMe0kzGRKk1je | match 3
+----+--------------------------------+
```

If I do:

```
$subscriptionPlans = SubscriptionPlan::where('active', 1)
            ->join('subscription_items', 'subscription_plans.stripe_plan', '=', 'subscription_items.stripe_plan')
            ->get();
```

I get the correct records that the user has.

I thought the opposite of that query would give me the plans the user doesn't have.:

```
$subscriptionPlans = SubscriptionPlan::where('active', 1)
            ->join('subscription_items', 'subscription_plans.stripe_plan', '!=', 'subscription_items.stripe_plan')
            ->get();
        dd($subscriptionPlans);
```

Note the operator `!=`

That doesn't work as I hoped. It actually outputs multiple/duplicate records of the `subscription_plans` table.

The `dd('$subscriptionPlans');` output way more items than plans due to the duplication:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1590 ▼
  #items: array:22 [▼
    0 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1589 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1588 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1587 ▶}
    3 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1586 ▶}
    4 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1585 ▶}
    5 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1584 ▶}
    6 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1583 ▶}
    7 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1582 ▶}
    8 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1581 ▶}
    9 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1580 ▶}
    10 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1579 ▶}
    11 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1578 ▶}
    12 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1577 ▶}
    13 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1576 ▶}
    14 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1575 ▶}
    15 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1574 ▶}
    16 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1573 ▶}
    17 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1572 ▶}
    18 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1571 ▶}
    19 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1472 ▶}
    20 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1491 ▶}
    21 => App\Models\SubscriptionPlan {#1485 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Answer:**

Here is the correct Laravel query based on the below answer by @FaNo_FN

```
   $subscriptionPlans =  DB::table('subscription_plans')
     ->leftJoin('subscription_items','subscription_items.stripe_plan','=','subscription_plans.stripe_plan')
     ->whereNull('subscription_items.stripe_plan')
     ->get();
```

Comment: Please don't post answer on question. Edit your question, write the self answer which solved your problem, and accept if you think that's the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little advice, post photos only when you can't explain things in textual format, especially when you're showing your table data. A textual value is much more easier to copy & paste if someone wants to attempt at helping you. Also, you don't have to show the exact data you're having unless it's necessary. You just need to re-create them with fake data and related columns.

Anyways, I can see this being done using a `LEFT JOIN` operator. Perhaps, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM subscription_plans sp LEFT JOIN subscription_items si 
ON sp.stripe_plan=si.stripe_plan
WHERE si.stripe_plan IS NULL;
```

The idea is simply to find any row values in `subscription_plans` table that doesn't match with `subscription_items`. I'm not sure how to convert this to you ORM of choice though but I think you should be able to figure it out.

[Here's a fiddle for reference (updated with current data sample)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d56ac42f4f7a8b62e2d8938b1a624a6)

Comment: I took your advice and updated my question. I'm going to go try and work in your query now. I'll let you know how it goes. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. I've updated the fiddle with your provided example data as well.

Comment: That worked perfect. The `leftJoin` and `whereNull` was the key. Thank you!!